# Move a word to a different column in multiple lines

Tags: awk, sed

I have a bunch of lines that look like:

```
some_command -arg1 -arg2 ITEM -arg3
```

I need to move `ITEM` right after `some_command`

The file does have comments etc. So I need to do the above operation only on lines beginning with `some_command`.

There are close to 1000 such lines and I can't image doing it manually. Even using block visual mode will be tricky because there is no alignment really.

I am thinking `awk` will be my friend here.The position of `ITEM` is fixed, so I know the column number. But how can I tell `awk` to print `$1` then `$6` and then all the other columns from `$2` to `$NF` except `$6`? And also only do this on lines beginning with `some_command`?

Comment: `awk '/^some_command/ { $1 = $1 " " $4; $4 = ""; } 1'`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Thank you for nice code, IMHO making $4 as NULL could cause spacing issue, though not tested it at all.

Comment: @WilliamPursell i see what you did there! smart fella you are! works perfect.. RavinderSingh13 you are right, it adds an extra space; but that's not an issue for me..

Comment: @shikhanshu: Hope my solution could help you too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@shikhanshu: Try:

```
awk '/some_command/{$2="ITEM" FS $2;sub(/.*/,"",$(NF-1))} 1'   Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '/some_command/{$2=$(NF-1) FS $2;sub(/.*/,"",$(NF-1))} 1'   Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks! This works too. Any advantage of replacing `/.*/` with `""` instead of just setting `$(NF-1)` to `""` ?

Comment: @shikhanshu: you are right as I have mentioned before it is to keeping the space same and not to mess up with them. Moreover $(NF-1) save us to hardcode the value of any field so each time let the number of fields be anything if you need always second last field, it should fly then. I hope this helps you. Keep learning and keep asking/sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

a sed version

```
sed -e '/^[[:blank:]]*#/b' -e 's/\(some_command\)\(.*\)[[:blank:]]\([^-][^[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)/\1 \3\2/' YourFile
```

Assuming your item doesn't start with a `-` like in yuour sample (easier), if not space is the separator and need a bit more code

awk version

```
awk '/^[[:blank:]]*some_command/ {t=$4; $4=$3; $3=$2; $2=t}7' YourFile
```